# How can I keep a script from running if user isn't viewing records in FORM VIEW?

Tags: filemaker

In Filemaker Pro 11, I've written a script that is script triggered to run on every instance of OnRecordLoad, however I don't want it to run when user is working in LIST or TABLE VIEWS.

Is there some code I can put at the beginning of my script that does something along the lines of this logic:

"If CURRENT VIEW does not = FORM VIEW then end script"

which would effectively end the script before it ran.

I'm new at working with FM and I can't figure out a way to check the current view status within a script. If that's not possible, is there a way to limit certain script triggers are enabled depending on which view (Form, List, or Table) the user is currently in?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Get(LayoutViewState) function (http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref2.32.50.html)

```
If[ Get ( LayoutViewState ) = 0 ]
    //They're in form view, do stuff
Else
    //They're in list view or table view, skip
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You script should include the following lines right at the beginning:

```
If[Get(LayoutViewState)<>0]{
    Exit Script[]
}
```

That basically ensures that the script will only run when  the user's layout is in Form View.

**Get(LayoutViewState)** returns:

- **0** for form view,
- **1** for list mode
- **2** for Table view.

A similar function is Get(WindowMode) that returns:

- **0** for Browse mode
- **1** for Find mode
- **2** for Preview mode

Hope this helps.